# Compare two webpages based on their DOM

Tags: dom, compare

I'm wondering if there's a library around which allows you do something like http://tool.motoricerca.info/similarity-analyzer.phtml
The results lists something called HTML fingerprint which gives a percentage value of the probability of the two pages being structurally similar.